# Java 1.6 - determine symbolic links

Tags: java, java-6

In a DirectoryWalker class I want to find out if a File instance is actually a symbolic link to a directory (assuming, the walker walks on UNIX systems). Given, I already know the instance is a directory, would the following be a reliable condition to determine the symbolic link?

```
File file;
// ...      
if (file.getAbsolutePath().equals(file.getCanonicalPath())) {
    // real directory ---> do normal stuff      
}
else {
    // possible symbolic link ---> do link stuff
}
```

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175673/java-check-symbolic-link-file-existence

Comment: Java 1.7:  [java.nio.Files.isSymbolicLink(Path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isSymbolicLink%28java.nio.file.Path%29) - more a note for myself - I keep ending up back here!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The technique used in Apache Commons uses the canonical path to the parent directory, not the file itself. I don't think that you can guarantee that a mismatch is due to a symbolic link, but it's a good indication that the file needs special treatment.

This is [Apache code](https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java) (subject to [their license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)), modified for compactness.

```
public static boolean isSymlink(File file) throws IOException {
  if (file == null)
    throw new NullPointerException("File must not be null");
  File canon;
  if (file.getParent() == null) {
    canon = file;
  } else {
    File canonDir = file.getParentFile().getCanonicalFile();
    canon = new File(canonDir, file.getName());
  }
  return !canon.getCanonicalFile().equals(canon.getAbsoluteFile());
}
```

Comment: Hmm, Gray and erickson: in fact it seems to work fine even if it links to a file in the same directory. Do you have an unit test illustrating your point?

Comment: This does not work on Windows with NTFS (when symlink is created with mklink).

Comment: This has one problem in that it fails to discover symbolic links that point to missing files.  I think there needs to be a `file.exists()` test here additionally.

Answer (score 15):

Java 1.6 does not provide such low level access to the file system. Looks like [NIO 2](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=203), which should be included in Java 1.7, will have support for symbolic links. [A draft of the new API](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/index.html) is available. Symbolic links [are mentioned there](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/package-summary.html#links), [creating](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/Path.html#createSymbolicLink(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) and [following](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/Path.html#readSymbolicLink()) them is possible. I'm not exactly sure that which method should be used to find out whether a file is a symbolic link. There's [a mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/jsr203-interest) for discussing NIO 2 - maybe they will know.

Answer (score 15):

Also, watch out for `file.isFile()` and `file.isDirectory()` both returning results based on the resolved file and therefore both returning `false` when `file` refers to a symlink where the target doesn't exist.

(I know this isn't a useful answer in itself but it tripped me up a couple of times so thought I should share)

Comment: I never would have considered this scenario.  Nice mention.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like [`getCanonicalPath()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath()) can do other things that might make it different from the absolute path.

> This method first converts this pathname to absolute form if necessary, as if by invoking the getAbsolutePath() method, and then maps it to its unique form in a system-dependent way. This typically involves removing redundant names such as "." and ".." from the pathname, resolving symbolic links (on UNIX platforms), and converting drive letters to a standard case (on Microsoft Windows platforms).

But it might work for the vast majority of your use cases; your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

If you are already coding something specifically for *nix, then you could do a shell command from Java like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"test", "-h", yourFileName});
p.waitFor();
if (p.exitValue() == 0) 
   System.out.println("This file is a symbolic link");
else
   System.out.println("This file is not a symbolic link");
```

That's very specific to *nix, but it does at least work.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to reply to such an old post, but I was looking for a solution for Windows systems some time back, and some of the previous answers didn't work out for me.  If you're not concerned with cross platform compatibility and only need a solution for Windows, the following technique worked well for my purposes.

```
File f = new File("whatever file or folder");
if (f instanceof ShellFolder) {
  ShellFolder sf = (ShellFolder)f;
  if (sf.isLink()) {
    // Your code when it's a link
  }
}
```

Comment: `ShellFolder` seems to be `sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder` in `rt.jar`

Comment: I dont think "new File()" will produce an instance of ShellFolder dynamically. It does work as a result of FileChoser.

Answer (score -2):

I thought I would share some good fortune I had in dealing with this issue.  I am using JDK 1.6.0_23 and so I cannot benefit from NIO2.  I am building and running on Windows 7 /x64 ONLY so mileage may vary in other environments.  Unfortunately, other solutions here did not work for me in avoiding NullPointerExceptions caused when attempting to traverse a junction (probably because junction != symlink....).  While I am not constrained by JDK version, I decided to keep at the problem for a bit longer.

I had this code which would cause a NullPointerException if used on a symbolic link or when encountering the 'System Volume Information' directory.  (Note, traverseItem.f() returns an object of type java.io.File)

```
if (traverseItem.f().isDirectory) {
    for (File item : traverseItem.f().listFiles()) {
```

So, it is supposedly a directory but calling listFiles() on it causes an NPE.  What to do?  I spied the list() method and wondered if it would exhibit the same behavior.  What I discovered was the following:

Calling list() on a File describing an empty folder returns a String[] array of length zero.  However, calling list() on a File describing a junction which would otherwise crash from listFiles() returns null

I was able to avoid the NullPointerExceptions by adding the following test before calling listFiles()

```
    String[] contents = traverseItem.f().list();
    if (contents != null) {  //Non-traversible if null, possibly junction or ???
```

It remains to exhaustively test all cases of junction, symbolic link, hard link, and dare I mention it, shortcut, but this may help some.

Comment: Your explanation is all over the place, seems almost entirely irrelevant in most places, mostly inaccurate in others, and your code snippets are massively incomplete. I'd give this 2 downvotes if I could.