# Are there known discrepencies between Apache FileUtils.isSymlink and Java7's Files.isSymbolicLink()?

Tags: java, apache-commons, symlink, java-7

While debugging on my Windows 7 64 bit machine, I noticed that there is a symlink folder, that `FileUtils.isSymlink()` returns false for.

Java7's `Files.isSymbolicLink()` works correctly. Is this known? Should i report a bug?

Comment: See also: [Determine whether a file is a junction (in Windows) or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733275/determine-whether-a-file-is-a-junction-in-windows-or-not). Junctions are different from symbolic links on NTFS.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a bug. Reported issue: [IO-295
FileUtils.isSymlinks misses symlink folders on Windows](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IO-295).

> #### Description
>
> I created a symlink folder via mklink. Then, while
> debugging, I noticed that FileUtils.isSymlink() returns false on this
> directory, while Java 7's Files.isSymbolicLink() returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a bug.

FileUtils.isSymlink() is not supported in Windows. It always returns false for windows and its mentioned in the javadoc.

Note: the current implementation always returns false if the system is detected as Windows using FilenameUtils.isSystemWindows()

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#isSymlink%28java.io.File%29