# Detecting a symlink in Java

Tags: java, unix, filesystems, symlink

Given a Java 'File' object, how can I detect whether or not it refers to a symlink?

(If it helps/matters, I know the file refers to a directory, not to a file)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Also you can use [isSymbolicLink(Path path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isSymbolicLink%28java.nio.file.Path%29) method. It will be more reliable.

```
java.io.File file = ...;
boolean isSymbolicLink = Files.isSymbolicLink(file.toPath());
```

Similar examples from Java Doc '[Detecting a Symbolic Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html#detect)'.

Comment: There's a caveat - like `Files.exists`, `Files.isSymbolicLink` can sometimes return a false negative.

Comment: @Hakanai could you provide an example?

Comment: @auraham if an exception occurs when checking for the information, the method will swallow the exception and return false, regardless of whether the file is a symbolic link. Because of that, in many cases, for `Files.exists()`, what you often really want is `!Files.notExists()`. But it wasn't the case 100% of the time either. This mess caused us to ban usage of the methods in our codebase, redirecting calls to our own versions which throw the exception.

Answer (score 36):

[`File.getCanonicalPath()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29) resolves symlinks

> A canonical pathname is both absolute and unique. The precise definition of canonical form is system-dependent. This method first converts this pathname to absolute form if necessary, as if by invoking the getAbsolutePath()  method, and then maps it to its unique form in a system-dependent way. This typically involves removing redundant names such as "." and ".." from the pathname, resolving symbolic links (on UNIX platforms), and converting drive letters to a standard case (on Microsoft Windows platforms).

I assume you can compare the result of `getCanonicalPath()` and `getAbsolutePath()`.

Update: It appears this question has already been asked - check [the answers there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813710/java-1-6-determine-symbolic-links)

Comment: Sounds like it might work - I wonder how expensive it is to call on a real file-system object (I assume it's having to check each directory up the tree, where as I only care about the last one)...

Comment: Thanks - Using Apache's commons IO as noted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813710/java-1-6-determine-symbolic-links/813730#813730 seems like a good solution.