# Get realPath from alias using Java in Mac

Tags: java, macos, path

I am trying to get the real path from a symbolic link but no success.

> Operating system: Mac 
>   Java version: Java 9

I am seeing the documentation from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html

I have following folder structure on my computer...

```
 I have kept real file is in 
 /Users/Name/Desktop/realfile.txt

 I have created a symbolic link of realfile.txt as realfile_alias and kept it in
 /Users/Name/WorkSpace/Test/data/realfile_alias 

 I am running java program from
 /Users/Name/WorkSpace/Test/src folder.
```

My source code:

```
String sPath = "data/realfile_alias"  // this is relative path. I have kept the symbolic link in data folder. 

Path path = Paths.get(sPath);
boolean isSymbolic = Files.isSymbolicLink(path); 
// it returns true

Path realPath = Files.readSymbolicLink(path);
```

> ```
> realPath is just returning 
> /Users/Name/WorkSpace/Test/data/realfile_alias
>
> But I expect it to be 
>
> /Users/Name/Desktop/realfile.txt
> ```

How can I get the real path from symbolic path?

Comment: Have you tried File.getCanonicalPath() ? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490387/7417402

Comment: how did you create the symbolic link? Also, could you please post the output of `ls -la /Users/Name/WorkSpace/Test/data/realfile_alias` ?

Comment: output of ls -la: 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 sarker  staff  12 Feb  1 18:41 realfile_alias -> realfile.txt

Comment: thanks, it looks like a symbolic link indeed. Have you tried setting `sPath` to the absolute path i.e. `/Users/Name/WorkSpace/Test/data/realfile_alias` ?