# How to read command line ouput from Java (via Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...))

Tags: java, command-line, console, runtime, exec

I'm trying to present some information in a Swing application about the existance of symlinks.
The GUI has a `JTextArea resultTextArea` and a `JTextField statusField`. This is the code inside the Dialog class:

```
public void checkForSymLinks(File... dirs) {
    for (File dir : dirs) {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("find -type l", null, dir);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                resultTextArea.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SymbolicLinkSearchResultDialog.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    statusField.setText("SymLinks found! // FIXME");
}
```

I tried and replaced `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("find -type l", null, dir);` by:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("find -type l");
pb.directory(dir).redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
```

But that did not help.

The problem is that it somehow neither writes anything to the `resultTextArea` nor reaches the code to set the statusField in the last line. It seems to hang somewhere, alhough the GUI stays responsive.

I get the following stacktrace upon *closing* the dialog:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "find -type l" (in directory "/home/johndoe/Desktop/test"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1024)
```

I already tried `/usr/bin/find type -l` and many other things...
Any ideas what I'm done wrong?

PS: Operationg system is Linux.

Weird thing:

```
def symLinkCheck(dirs: Array[File]) = {                              
  dirs.foreach{ dir =>                                                        
    val p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("find -type l", null, dir)                    
    val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream)) 
    var line: String = null
    while({line = in.readLine; line} != null){
      println(line)
    }
  }
}
```

I tried this code in Scala and it worked without a problem. I'm not really sure anymore if my problem is maybe related to Swing?

***EDIT: The problem is definitely related to Swing.***

If I call the method before `theGUI.setVisible(true)` it works, but after that it doesn't.

I already tried `SingUtilities.invokeLater` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Problem: The method was not called from the event dispatch thread, after the GUI was constrcuted.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which OS you're using. Assuming your `find` command syntax is correct (it's not correct on Mac OSX), I think you should be:

1. consuming both stdout and stderr. You need to do this *concurrently* to avoid blocking behaviour. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec/882795#882795) for more details
2. collecting the exit code from the spawned process via `Process.waitFor()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running a Unix command to find symlinks, you could do it in Java, by comparing the results of `File.getCanonicalPath()` and `File.getAbsolutePath()`.

More details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813710/java-1-6-determine-symbolic-links) question.

Comment: I already thought of this possibility before, but this doesn't work reliable.