# How to check a file is shortcut file?

Tags: java, android

Following code fails to check the shortcut file. [code source](http://www.scribblethink.org/Xfiles/javasymlinks.html)
Suppose there is file `sdcard/1234567.mp3` which is not shortcut file even the absolute and canonical paths are different.

```
public static boolean isShortcutFile(File file) {
        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return !file.getAbsolutePath().equals(file.getCanonicalPath());
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Alternate way what i tried is checking the extension of a file is `.lnk` will it work for all case?

Comment: Have a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281612/android-determining-a-symbolic-link

Comment: @AntonMaiorov same checking is done there also

Comment: There is a simplified version in an answer by rds

Comment: i guess file.endsWith(".lnk ")  will work