# Android Music File Chooser Intent Issue

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-sdcard

I have an app that lets user choose music file from sdcard. To launch chooser intent I am using

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 0);
```

But I am getting different absolute paths depending on what method user choose. If user uses ES File Explorer then I get `/sdcard/Music/song.mp3` but if user uses some music app then I am getting `/storage/sdcard0/Music/song.mp3`. Its very confusing and my app requires me to know one final base path. 
`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns `/storage/sdcard0/`. Any help would be appreciated.
Note: in both cases

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(new File(soundPath).getAbsolutePath()); 
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
```

works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/sdcard` is usually [symlinked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the real(*) path in the filesystem (the `/storage` one) to stay compatible with early Android devices where `/sdcard` was the default.

Using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is the method you should use. There is no guarantee that `/sdcard` or `/storage/sdcard0` will work if you hardcode that path. Device manufacturers can use pretty much any filesystem layout they want but they will make sure that `Environment` knows the correct path.

---

(*) Starting Honeycomb & the "unified storage model" the real path is actually something like `/data/media` which is loop-mounted via fuse to `/storage/sdcard0` (or whatever `Environment` tells you) to enforce the correct permission required for the [`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.

[Impromptu Q&A Session With Android Engineer Dan Morrill Brings To Light Reasons Behind Galaxy Nexus' Lack Of USB Mass Storage](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/18/impromptu-qa-session-with-android-engineer-dan-morrill-brings-to-light-reasons-behind-galaxy-nexus-lack-of-usb-mass-storage/) - second question has some details.

---

`getAbsolutePath()` is by the way not working in the same way as it does for desktop Java apps. On Android, the current working directory / root is always `/`. So `getAbsolutePath()` would always return the same as `getPath()` does and will at most prefix the path with a `/`.

`Uri`s from `File` can be easily constructed via

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(soundPath));
```

that way you get a correct `Uri` using the `file://` scheme which is not the case (and could lead to errors) if you use `Uri.parse("/some/path")`

Comment: So I guess if path starts with `/sdcard/` then I could just replace it with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to ensure one final path.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh If you really need to unify the paths you get yes. You could also try if `File#getCanonicalPath` can do that automatically for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/813726/995891

Answer (score 1):

Getting full path and file name:

```
 Private String getPath(Uri u) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(u, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
```

use this on onActivityResult

String mpath = getPath(data.getData());