# How do I know if a file name is an alias in Android?

Tags: android, symlink

I am trying to figure out a method for finding removable SD cards in Android devices. I have found several methods that provide consistently good results. Sometimes I find two different file paths that seem to point to the exact same position.

For example:

`/mnt/sdcard`
and 
`/storage/sdcard0`

appear to point to the same location on some devices. My conclusion is that one of them is an alias, but both can be used to write to the SDcard. I am not too familiar with the use of aliasing, but **is there a way to find out if either or both of the files is an alias? Is it possible to determine the "real" file path?**

I know that Android is built on a Linux kernal, and has adopted some of the file system conventions. Is there a standard Linux way of doing this?

Comment: This is called symbolic link and you can find the answer here: [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813710/java-1-6-determine-symbolic-links)

Comment: I think you mean it's a symlink

Comment: @timmied: It could also be a hardlink.

Comment: I know it is a symlink , don't have the resource for it a.t.m. read it somewhere on XDA-devs  But could we easily detect what it is, with a similar script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean symlink.

This is essentially how they do in [Apache Commons](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/io/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.java?view=markup) (subject to [their license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)):

Also mentioned in this answer: [Java 1.6 - determine symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813710/java-1-6-determine-symbolic-links)

```
public static boolean isSymlink(File file) throws IOException {
  File canon;
  if (file.getParent() == null) {
    canon = file;
  } else {
    File canonDir = file.getParentFile().getCanonicalFile();
    canon = new File(canonDir, file.getName());
  }
  return !canon.getCanonicalFile().equals(canon.getAbsoluteFile());
}
```

Comment: Hmm, while you quote the other answer here and link to its source, isn't this a duplicate of Mr.Me's answer?

Comment: Nope this is an actual answer to the question. The answer is however a duplicate of many other good answers given to duplicate questions like this.  Might this question not be flagged as duplicate (I flagged it) people can still see a right answer.