# Path on Android for Intent

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-intent

I am working in Unity, and I am using intent so my app would receive the file path of the file that I used to launch my app which in this case is a .CSV file.

```
AndroidJavaClass UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

    AndroidJavaObject intent = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getIntent");
```

This is how I get the data path.

```
string result = intent.Call<string>("getDataString");
```

This is the path it gives:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/map4.csv
```

The path I need:

```
/storage/sdcard0/map4.csv
```

Otherwise I can't acces the file on that path.

How could I get the 2nd type of path?

Comment: It may be a permissions issue [Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed) . You may need to add the read files permission in the manafest or Grand read on the intent like  "intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);"

Comment: The problem is that actual path doesn't work, only relative path

Comment: It doesn't seem to be permission related, as I get a path, but I believe this to be an issue with the method. A different method should be called for getting the path. But I have tried every path related method.

Comment: Interesting, maybe [Reference Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841380/android-disambiguating-file-paths) and using the  getCanonicalPath() method?

Comment: It is all good now. Problem was that it replaces % with %20 and so on, needed to decudeURL

Comment: How did the path get URL encoded?

Comment: result = WWW.UnEscapeURL(result);
Where result is the Path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Documentation [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) shows:

```
getDataString()
    "The same as getData(), but returns the URI as an encoded String."
```

So it makes sense to need to "WWW.UnEscapeURL(result)"