# Getting the actual file, given the Symbolic Link on java6

Tags: java, io, filesystems, symlink, java-6

I've a directory on remote machine in which I have symbolic links pointing to actual files, and I am supposed to read the actual files given the symbolic link.

I can do it, if I can find the actual `filePath`, which is pointed to by the Symbolic Link.

I know that if we were using Java 7 we could do it using NIO2's classes (namely `Path`, `Paths` and `Files`), but we can't upgrade to JDK7 for several reasons.

The same thing I do not see in Java 6. What should be the work around for the same? I have already tried going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813710/java-1-6-determine-symbolic-links) but it didn't help.

Comment: Try and execute `readlink -f thefile` on the remote host; a non zero exit status means the link has no valid target, otherwise it outputs the result on stdout. But doesn't `.getCanonicalFile()` work?

Comment: Nope fge, getCanonicalFile doesn't work.It gives you the location of the symbolic link itself. About : readlink -f thefile  could you elaborate please ?

Comment: What don't you understand exactly?

Comment: readlink -f symLink doesn't return anything except canonicalPath of the symbolLink which points to itself not the actualfile location.

Comment: Sorry, that should be readlink -e

Comment: ...and `getCanonicalPath()` not `getCanonicalFile()`.

Comment: getCanonicalPath() will point to the location of the symLink. BTW : readLink -f link using java's runtime.exec. how do you get the return value ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I can give an answer. Strange.

This program demonstrates getCanonicalPath() and it does indeed resolve the symlink.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File link = new File("testlink");
        System.out.println(link.getCanonicalPath());
    }
}
```

and running it produces:

```
[jon@dragon ~]$ ls -l testlink
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jon jon 9 Apr 15 13:31 testlink -> Test.java
[jon@dragon ~]$ java Test
/home/jon/Test.java
```