# Detect if a File is a symbolic link in Java 8

Tags: java, macos, ubuntu, centos, symlink

How can I detect whether a `File` `f` is a symbolic link (in the unix sense, as created by `ln -s source target`) or a normal file/directory?

I am using `Java 8` and `OS X`, `CentOS` and `Ubuntu`.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813710/java-1-6-determine-symbolic-links) they kind of solve it for `Java 6`. Is there something better in `Java 8`?

I would like to later use this in order to handle files and directories on a different file system in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes.isSymbolicLink()` available since Java 7