# Calling delete() on a File object, are the effects immediately visible?

Tags: android, synchronization, delete-file, android-file

If I call `File.delete()` are the effects on the underlying file system immediately visible? Can I write to the same file name in the same process/thread after without worrying about bad things happening? If not, is there a way to sync the underlying file system with just a `File` object?

Answer (score 0):

File.delete() return a boolean telling you if the file has been correctly deleted.
So you could write something like :

```
if(yourFile.delete()) {
  //keep doing what you want. You are now sure file has been deleted !
}
```

Also, before writing a new file, you could check if a file with the same name already exists.

From Oracle documentation :

```
Returns:
true if and only if the file or directory is successfully deleted; false otherwise
```

[Oracle source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete())

[Also there is a SO thread that might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906523/thread-safe-creating-and-deleting-file-in-java)

Comment: I'm not sure if the boolean means that the file is no longer visible in the file system or if it may be actually be deleted at a later time?