# How to get the intermediate symlink using Java

Tags: java, unix

Symlink A is pointing to a symlink B. Symlink B is pointing to a target file C. While trying to get what symlink A is pointing using `getCanonicalPath()` I am getting the target C and not the intermediate link B. But my requirement is to get the intermediate link B.

I have searched a lot but couldn't get the expected result. Any help is very much appreciated.
P.S: right now I could use only Java 6.

I shall explain my scenario bit clearer.

bash-3.2$ ls -ltr
drwxr-xr-x 8 user user 4096 Jan 29 22:34 jdk1.6.0_45
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 58 Jun 17 04:53 jdk6 -> jdk1.6.0_45
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 51 Jun 22 09:41 current -> jdk6

*Code I tried:*

```
File file="/path/to/current";<br/>
String target=file.getCanonicalPath();
```

Now my "target" string is coming as "**jdk1.6.0_45**"..since current points to jdk6 which inturn points to jdk1.6.0_45..But my **requirement** is to get what excatly current points to i.e) **jdk6**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813710/java-1-6-determine-symbolic-links) link has only how to get the end target and not the intermediate links..But that is what I want.Please help

Comment: Please add a concrete example of what you've tried to do with some code.

Comment: I think with native Java 6 there is no way. Probably you can run some shell command. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813710/java-1-6-determine-symbolic-links